# How to test for object existence in Firebird SQL?

Tags: firebird

I need to test whether various types of database objects exist in a given database, and I don't know how to formulate these tests in Firebird SQL. Each test has the form "Does object of type *X* with name *Y* exist?". For example, I need to test whether a table with a given name exists.  The object types I need to test are:

- Table
- View
- Domain
- Trigger
- Procedure
- Exception
- Generate
- UDF
- Role

One can find how to query for a given table on the Internet, but the other types are more difficult to find ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think a lot of what you are asking can be found at [this forum post](http://dn.codegear.com/article/25259).  If you want to dive a little deeper, [this site](http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/db/interbase/using_interbase_system_tables/using_interbase_system_tables.html) seems to have a graphical representation of the tables.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need to query against the system tables to reliably get that information.  Here's a tutorial that looks like it can help:

http://www.alberton.info/firebird_sql_meta_info.html

Answer (score 0):

Every year, Martijn Tonies made a session in Firebird Conference

so find in timetable 
in 2005 
http://www.ibphoenix.com/main.nfs?a=ibphoenix&page=fb_conf_timetable_2005

in 2006 
http://www.ibphoenix.com/main.nfs?a=ibphoenix&page=fb_conf_timetable_2006

there is also for 2007 and 2008

http://www.firebirdconference.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3&Itemid=3

but I don't know where to download papers